# Proving convergence of sequence with induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I have a sequence defined as $a_{1}=\sqrt{a}$ and $a_{n}=\sqrt{1+a_{n-1}}$ and I need to prove that it has an upper bound and therefore is convergent. So i have assumed that the sequence has a limit and by squaring I got that the limit is $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ only $ \mathbf{if}$ it converges.

What methods are there for proving convergence? I am trying to show that $a_{n}<\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ by induction but could use some help since I have never done induction proof before.

Progress:

Step 1(Basis): Check if it holds for lowest possible integer: Since $a_{0}$ is not defined, lowest possible value is $2$.

$a_{2}=\sqrt{1+a_{1}}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{a}}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}}< \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Step 2: Assume it holds for $k\in \mathbb{N},k\geq 3$. If we can prove that it holds for $n=k+1$ we are done and therefore it holds for all  $k$.

This is were i am stuck:  $a_{k+1}=\sqrt{1+a_{k}}$. I don't know how to proceed because I don't know where I am supposed to end.

Comment: What is $a$?${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use the [**Monotone Convergence Theorem: MCT**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Theorem). That is, show that $a_n$ is monotone increasing, and bounded above. Increasing should be evident...

***Find any upper bound**: $\,3\,$ maybe?; there's no need to find the least upper bound if you only need to prove convergence.*

If you can do that, then by the Monotone Convergence Theorem, you can conclude the sequence converges.

Then you are done, if you *only* need to prove convergence.

---

THEN, if you want to find the value to which the sequence converges,
assume $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$. Then $L$ must satisfy $L=\sqrt{1+L}$, and solve for $L$.

Comment: +1 for the nice insights, yet...The sequence is monotone increasing *from some definite index n* and on, depending heavily on what $\,a>0\,$ is. Before that index, the sequence is decreasing, and there can be lots of indexes with that characteristic. In fact, I think it is possible to prove for any $\,k\in\Bbb N\,$ there exists $\,a(k)=a>0\,$ big enough so that $\,\{a_n\}_{n\leq k}\,$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is to show that is bounded above by $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Why don't you prove something easier, that is bounded above by $3$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that it is monotone and bounded. This guarantees convergence; then suppose $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$. Then $L$ must satisfy $$L=\sqrt{1+L}.$$ Solve for $L$.

Comment: There's an induction problem on sequences here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510591/use-of-induction-on-a-sequence if u guys are interested.

Comment: @mespebjidom: It seems you already have a fine answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x}-x$. We find that $f'(x) = \frac 1 {2\sqrt{1+x}} -1 <0$. This means that $f$ is a strictly decreasing function. Set $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$.

We now that $f(\phi)=0$. We must then have that $f(x)>0$ if $x<\phi$ and $f(x)<0$ if $x>\phi$. So $a_{n+1}>a_n$ if $a_n< \phi$ and $a_{n+1} < a_n$ if $a_n > \phi$.

I claim that if $a_1<\phi$ then $a_n < \phi$ for all $n$. This is proven by induction. Assume that $a_k < \phi$. Then $a_{k+1}^2 = a_k +1 < 1+\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}= \frac{6+2\sqrt{5}}{4} =\phi^2$. So $a_{k+1} < \phi$ and by induction we get that $a_n < \phi$ for all $n$.

If $a_1<\phi$ we thus know that we get a bounded increasing sequence. All bounded increasing sequences converge. To deal with the case when $\sqrt {a_1}>\phi$ is left as an exercise.